# of using a same twig syntax for backend and frontend templating

Tags: twig

I've been wondering lately about the possibility to use a templating system with a "same" syntax as Twig for client-side templating, and about its integration with Twig. Found [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.com/swig/), which seems to be the "Twig for javascript".

Using a same syntax could have several benefits:

- no need to learn yet another syntax,
- portable templates: a same block could be used for both frontend and/or backend templating, depending on architecture.
- you name it ...

However, a few challenges would arise:

- I would need a mechanism to define which tags/blocks/parts in a template are dedicated to frontend parsing. The `{% raw %}` tag does the job, but ...
- aiming at portable templates would speak for very granular blocks and the possibility to "include as raw". For example: I'd like to gather in the `<head>` of my main HTML file all the blocks that I want to be available to the frontend templating engine, each one wrapped within a `<script>` tag. So I would need to "raw-include" these blocks.

Has anyone used Twig in conjunction with Swig, or any other javascript templating system with a syntax that somewhat collides with Twig's syntax?
How would you manage/organize your templates so that you can easily use a template also/just in the frontend?

Comment: I think the swig you refer to isn't the same swig as most of the other questions tagged swig or what the tag wiki for it describes.

Comment: Though it's not for the exact purpose you want, check out [twig.js](https://github.com/schmittjoh/twig.js).

Comment: Did you manage to do this?i'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer: This is an open answer to an open question, keep that in mind 
please. I'm sharing my experience as there's no simple, single way of answering this question.*

I'm a frontend webdeveloper working closely with symfony guys. Back in the days, we used twig and mustache templates together. Mustache templates duplictad twig wherever there was need for ajax calls. Quite obviously this was a gigantic maintenance overhead.

I divided my answer into two parts addressing two separate issues; structuring templates to make them easily frontend-able, and adding javascript implementation of twig.

---

**Templates structure**

The first step we took towards logically organizing templates, was dividing them into **page level**, **functional** and **presentational** templates.

**Page level** templates are templates defining general containers for app contents. 
Think of:

- user unauthorized
- user authorized
- email

**Functional** templates are just one step deeper. They are prefabricates used to build up the whole page. Usually they are the point where data from backend is being put to. Think of a list of users in a container, for example. Functional template is the container, which includes presentational templates, passing the data to it.

**Presentational** templates are just components with no logic (no data transformation), meant to be fed with data. This components can be nested. (F.e. *Button* and *title* are both included by *CTA* component). Presentational components is the finest grain of our building blocks.

Organising the code this way took much time, but allowed us have a clear distinction on components which have to be able to be frontend-renderable and ones that can be logic-heavy.

---

**Twig.js**

The next step was integrating (as suggested in one of the comments) [twig.js](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js).

> I'd like to gather in the  of my main HTML file all the blocks that I want to be available to the frontend templating engine, each one wrapped within a   tag. So I would need to "raw-include" these blocks.

With twig.js you don't need to worry about making templates available for the frontend. You can just provide the url, and if the template extends or includes some other templates, the'll be loaded asynchronously. So the twig template that is fed with json data, gets rendered by javascript, and there's no need of additional templating engine.

---

I have never run any performance tests. Although i can imagine that twig.js is considerably slower than mustache, rendering only logic-less components in twig.js can improve performance a great bit.

If i didn't address anything just please let me know. I'm eager to discuss this subject further.